# Uploading files to s3 from local machine to s3 using carrierwave in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am trying to upload the files from my local machine to amazon s3 using carrierwave. Actually I want to write the migration for the above operations. I need to move the images that are stored locally to amazon. Can anybody tell me how should I perform the above operations using the methods of carrierwave.
Btw I am also using `Carrierwave_direct` on top of carrierwave but I don't think that would affect my storage methods.

I executed `uploader.store!(/local/path/to/file)` but it fails with the following error:

> You tried to assign a String or a Pathname to an uploader, for
>   security reasons, this is not allowed.

Is there any other way I can send in the path info in the method?

I also tried executing:

```
new_file.asset = File.open('full/path') #asset is where my uploader is mounted
```

In this case, when I try `new_file.save!`, it successfully saves but when I try to get the url by doin `new_file.asset.url` it shows empty. I don't know why

Heres my uploader:

```
module DirectUploader
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    extend ActiveModel::Naming

    process :set_content_type
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def store_dir
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end

    # override the url to return absolute url if available and
    # revert back to standard functionality if it is not available
    def url
      if model.absolute_url.nil?
        super
      else
        model.absolute_url
      end
    end

    def filename
      @random = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(model.latest_time.to_s)
      "#{@random}.#{File.extname(original_filename)}" if original_filename
    end

    def policy_doc(options={})
      options[:expiration] ||= self.class.upload_expiration
      options[:max_file_size] ||= self.class.max_file_size

      doc = {
          'expiration' => Time.now.utc + options[:expiration],
          'conditions' => [
              ["starts-with", "$utf8", ""],
              ["starts-with", "$authenticity_token", ""],
              ["starts-with", "$key", store_dir],
              {"bucket" => fog_directory},
              {"acl" => acl},
              ["content-length-range", 1, options[:max_file_size]]
          ]
      }
      doc['conditions'] << {"success_action_redirect" => success_action_redirect} if success_action_redirect
      doc
    end

    def policy(options={})
      Base64.encode64(policy_doc(options).to_json).gsub("\n","")
    end
  end
end
```

And there is no problem in carrierwave configuration because I can upload the files using form/html. Its just that I am finding problems during migration.

Comment: Can you post your configuration for carrierwave? Also do you need carrierwave to do any processing for you or are you just strictly uploading the files?

Comment: here the uploader file that I use:

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
uploader.store!(File.new('/local/path/to/file'))
```

When I'm running tests, I use:

```
uploader.store! File.open(Rails.root.join("spec/support/file.png"))
```